# Does Islam reference the solar system, with planets revolving around the sun?

Tags: quran, science, scientific-proof, universe

After numerous discoveries by mankind, the world now believes that we are on a planet which is in a solar system revolving around the Sun.

Does Islam have any reference(s) to this? What is the concept of this?

Comment: I don't see why not, as long as we also believe that it was ultimately created by Allah.

Comment: you mean now or as of then?

Comment: Please refrain from using comments to answer questions.

Comment: I had read about this somewhere, can anyone give any reference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you refer to this verse.

> [21:33 And it is He who created the night and the day and the sun and the moon; all [heavenly bodies] in an orbit are swimming.](http://quran.com/21/33)

The verse also points to the fact that also the sun is part of a larger system having its own orbit of revolving around the galaxy (or any larger entity, that is).

Since Islam started long before these scientific discoveries its role was not to prove or disprove any specific scientific fact, Instead, since it is a religion to govern ALL aspect of life its role was (and is) to create a healthy environment for science to flourish. Urging muslims to (discover) and (use) natural resources for the better benefit of mankind.

Comment: this is wrong translation of the verse!

Comment: Indeed, it is a complex translation. IIRC, some claim the closer translation is "sphere" - this is tricky, as it *suggests* (although it is admittedly vague) that this is then the moon and sun orbiting the earth in a sphere - the exact *opposite* of what the question asks (i.e. geocentric rather than heliocentric).

Comment: The verse makes no reference to galaxies!

Answer (score 0):

If you people have confusion about the orbit in which the sun is swimming, you can clear this idea that Islam has given by studying and researching on "Galactic center" and "Galactic year".

Comment: This is more of a comment. Please use comment section to for such things.